# Vue 3 reactive or ref window propery / variable

Tags: properties, window, vuejs3, reactive, ref

How to assign window property reactivity in components of Vue 3?

When use Vue via CDN I can use something like:

```
let x = Vue.reactive({})
```

and in data return to use it in project

```
data(){
    return{
      a: x
}
```

But when I use the same way in project with build I cannot achieve same thing.

Thank you for any help or idea.

Comment: What do you mean by "project with build"? Is it using `npm` with `node_modules`? If yes, you can just import from the module like that `import { reactive } from 'vue'`
[Document](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/reactivity-fundamentals.html#declaring-reactive-state)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.